# Joining two data sets on a variable with different character length

Tags: sas

I'm trying to join two data sets on a variable with different character lengths with the following code, but neither works and I'm not sure why.

```
 FROM A   AS ROLLACT
    LEFT JOIN MALT.CUST            AS ACCOUNT   

    /*    ON  (ROLLACT.ACCTNO, BEST.)  = INPUT( ACCOUNT.ACCT_NO,BEST.) */
          ON  INPUT (ROLLACT.ACCTNO, 30.)  = INPUT( ACCOUNT.ACCT_NO,30.)
```

In this case `ROLLACT.ACCTNO` is a character variable with length 30 and `ACCT_NO` is a character variable with length 19.

So I'm confused why I can't convert both to a specific length (using Input(30.)) with:

```
ON  INPUT (ROLLACT.ACCTNO, 30.)  = INPUT( ACCOUNT.ACCT_NO,30.)
```

I'm also trying to convert both into numeric with:

```
 ON  (ROLLACT.ACCTNO, BEST.)  = INPUT( ACCOUNT.ACCT_NO,BEST.)
```

Does anyone have suggestions about how to do this within the Proc Sql step?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to do anything special to compare character strings of different lengths.  SAS will ignore the trailing spaces.  Obviously if the actual value of the longer variable has more than 19 characters it will never match the value that is limited to 19 characters.

The INPUT() function does not change the length.  If is used to convert strings into values. If you use a numeric informat, as in your examples, then the result is a number.  But you cannot convert a 30 digit string exactly into a number.  SAS stores numbers as 8 byte floating point values so the maximum number of decimal digits of precision is 15.

Comment: Ideally, I would have simply used: ON  ROLLACT.ACCTNO  = ACCOUNT.ACCT_NO - which I think works with a data step and simply merging data sets. However, I would have liked to incorporate it into the Proc Sql, which seems to be more particular.  So does someone know how to deal with formats in the Proc Sql step?

Comment: PROC SQL uses the same functions as other SAS code. Unless you have pushed the query into an external database. In that case the you will need to use the language of the external database.

Answer (score 0):

a simple substr does the trick : `ON  (SUBSTR(ROLLACT.ACCTNO, 1,19))  = ACCOUNT.ACCT_NO`